# Difference between elements in one array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm learning Java and I trying to construct a method for my homework. It takes as argument an `Array` and returns the difference between its elements (as absolute value).

For example:  array {7,8,5,7,2}

the difference between elements 0 and 1 is 1 (=7−8)

the difference between elements 1 and 2 is 3 (=8−5)

the difference between elements 2 and 3 is 2 (=5-7)

the difference between elements 3 and 4 is 5 (=7−2)

the difference between elements 4 and 0 is 5 (=2-7)

If there are multiple candidates the method will return the one with the greatest index. In this example, the last one. If the `array` is empty, then the method must return `−1`.

I have some problems in my code (as you can see) and the biggest one is that my method returns only the last `diff` and not the biggest one with the higher index. Can someone help me? I'm not figuring out how to solve this problem.

```
public static int MaxDiff(int[] array){

        int diff = 0;

        if (array.length == 0){   // Checks for empty array
            return -1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; ++i){

            if(i == array.length){
                diff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[0]);
            } else {
                diff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[i+1]); // Mistake. Can be
                                                        // bigger than array
            }
        }

        return diff;
    }
```

Comment: the code you showed will give you `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` Exception

Comment: Also: Don't use an `if` inside the loop to check, if it's the last iteration. Just add the code after the loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed a little and then your code works correctly.

```
public static int MaxDiff(int[] array){

    int diff = 0;

    if (array.length == 0){ 
        return -1;
    }

    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; ++i){

        diff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[i+1]);
        if(max < diff)
            max = diff;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set diff only if it is bigger than it already is.

```
int newDiff;
if(i == array.length - 1){
    newDiff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[0]);
} else {
    newDiff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[i+1]);
}
if(newDiff > diff)
    diff = newDiff;
```

Also as @singhakash says the index of the last element of an array of size `n` is `n - 1`, not `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Create one instance variable maxDiff and update if you find diff greater than current computation diff in the loop. like

```
maxDiff = diff > maxDiff ? diff : maxDiff;
```

Finally return the maxDiff;

```
public static int MaxDiff(int[] array){

         //create a variable to hold maxDiff;
        int maxDiff = 0;
        int diff = 0;

        if (array.length == 0){   // Checks for empty array
            return -1;
        }

        //Change from <= to < (otherwise you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){

            if(i == array.length -1){
                diff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[0]);
            } else {
                diff = Math.abs(array[i] - array[i+1]); // Mistake. Can be
                                                        // bigger than array
            }
            //check for max
            maxDiff = diff > maxDiff ? diff : maxDiff;
        }

        return maxDiff;
    }
```

Comment: `i` will never be `==` to `array.length`

Comment: Yep. I just updated main part of the program. thanks.